# Proving that specific ring is isomorphic to quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

let's consider the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2] := {a+b\sqrt{2} \mid a,b\in \mathbb Z}$. I now want to prove that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]  \cong \mathbb Z [X]/(X^2-2)\mathbb Z[X]$.

What I found on the Internet is how to prove that $\mathbb C \cong \mathbb R[X]/(X^2+1)\mathbb R[X]$: http://people.virginia.edu/~mve2x/3354_Fall2010/lecture26.pdf (page 3)

I really like their approach there because it is clear that they construct an explicit ring isomorphism. However, I cannot take their ring isomorphism because they explicitly exploit that $\mathbb R$ is a field ...

Kind regards,
MathIsFun

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $\Bbb Z[X]$ is a domain

Answer (score 2):

Take $\varphi :\mathbb Z[X]\to \mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ defined by $$\varphi (p(X))=p(\sqrt 2).$$
This is obviously surjective. Moreover $$\varphi (p(X))=0\iff X^2-2\mid p(X).$$
I let you conclude.

Comment: Can you expand on why $p(\sqrt{2})=0 \implies X^2-2 \ |  \ p(X)$ ?

Comment: Yes, I am currently stuck there as well ... If I arbitrarily choose $p(X) = X^3-\sqrt 8$, then it also holds that $p(\sqrt 2) = 0$, but how could I factorize $X^3-\sqrt 8$ s.t. one of its factors would be $X^2-2$? I tried polynomial long division, but didn't succeed.

Comment: @MathIsFun : $X^3-\sqrt 2\notin \mathbb Z[X]$. Notice that $X^2-2$ is irreducible on $\mathbb Z[X]$ (by Eisenstein criterion). In particular, $(X^2-2)$ is a maximal ideal. In other word, if $p(\sqrt{2})=0$, then  $p(X)\in  (X^2-2)$.

Comment: Yes, speaking for myself, it makes sense.